# Python OOP: School Practice Class Does Not Return The Expected Result

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to make some oop pratices with python and I tried to make some classes and instances of a School like this:

```
class School:
    def __init__(self,name,country):
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
        self.students = []
        self.courses = []

    def add_course(self,course):
        self.courses.append(course)
    
    def enroll_student(self,student):
        self.students.append(student)

class Person:
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Student: {self.firstname} {self.lastname}, ID: {self.student_id}, Age: {self.age}" 

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname,student_id,age):
        super().__init__(firstname,lastname)
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.age = age

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname,teacher_id,subject):
        super().__init__(firstname,lastname)
        self.teacher_id = teacher_id
        self.subject = subject

class Course:
    def __init__(self,title,teacher,credits):
        self.title = title
        self.teacher = teacher
        self.credits = credits

# Creating instances of the Student class
student1 = Student("Alice", "Johnson", "S123", 20)
student2 = Student("Bob", "Williams", "S456", 22)

# Creating instances of the Teacher class
teacher1 = Teacher("Professor", "Smith", "T789", "Mathematics")
teacher2 = Teacher("Dr.", "Johnson", "T101", "Physics")

# Creating instances of the Course class
course1 = Course("Math 101", teacher1, 3)
course2 = Course("Physics 201", teacher2, 4)

# Creating an instance of the School class
my_school = School("Example School", "Country")

# Adding courses to the school
my_school.add_course(course1)
my_school.add_course(course2)

# Enrolling students in the school
my_school.enroll_student(student1)
my_school.enroll_student(student2)

print(my_school.students)
```

So as you can see I tried `print(my_school.students)` to show the enrolled students of school but I get this as result:

**[<**main**.Student object at 0x00000128EEBAF4D0>, <**main**.Student object at 0x00000128EEBAF500>]**

So what's going wrong here?

Comment: replace `__str__` with `__repr__`.